# Cannot load sf package - R

Tags: r, r-sf

I installed the sf package, succesfully as it seems, but I am simply not able to load it with the command:

```
library(sf)
```

R just 'works' indefinitly, with the little stop sign next to the console, and I have to shut it down.

Does anybody know what is happening? Some of my coleagues are having the exact same issue.

Comment: R and package version? You can try updating both. Same behaviour when called from IDE vs base R?

Comment: So, it gives a different result in Base R: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf. R is 4.1, sf is 1.0-3

Comment: You need to debug further then, there can be different reasons of why did the ``sf`` fail, [example 1](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1158), [example 2](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1007) and so on. Google the exact _full_ message you're getting. Without all exact info we can only guess blindly